# how to update to cuda 10.2 on xavier agx?

Tags: cuda, tensorrt, onnx

I am trying to use onnx-trt but that requires TENSORRT_LIBRARY_MYELIN.
TENSORRT_LIBRARY_MYELIN requires trt 7. trt 7 requires cuda 10.2. cuda 10.2 can only be updated through the jetpack sdk manager. But I only see cuda 10.0 on there. How do I update to cuda 10.2?

Comment: You are assuming that there is actually a CUDA 10.2 release for the jetson agx. I suspect there is not

Comment: you were correct. According to their forums, tensorRT 7 is not compatible with the Xavier AGX at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorRT 7 hasn't been released for Jetson yet, stay tuned.